# how can I get the response message from Axis2 in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to integrate my webservice (Axis2) in spring integration: I have spring-axis2-message.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
 xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd">

 <chain input-channel="messageChannelIN" output-channel="messageChannelOUT">
  <ws:header-enricher    >
   <ws:soap-action value="getMessageService"/>
  </ws:header-enricher>
  <ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2-webservice/services/wservices?wsdl" reply-channel="messageChannelOUT"/>
 </chain>
 

 <!-- The response from the service is logged to the console. -->
 <stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="messageChannelOUT"  append-newline="true" />
 
</beans:beans>
```

And a TestAxis2.java

```html
package org.neos.spring.test;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolver;


public class TestAxis2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-axis2-message.xml");
  DestinationResolver<MessageChannel> channelResolver = new BeanFactoryChannelResolver(context);

  String requestXml = 
    "<getMessageService xmlns=\"http://service.ws.axis2.neos.org\">" + 
      "<name>HUGO</name>"
    + "</getMessageService>";

  // Create the Message object
  Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestXml).build();

  // Send the Message to the handler's input channel
  MessageChannel channel = channelResolver.resolveDestination("messageChannelIN");
  channel.send(message);
  
 }

}
```

The program run very well and I can see in the console the next response:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns:getMessageServiceResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.ws.axis2.neos.org"><ns:return>HELLO HUGO!, WELCOME TO WEBSERVICE AXIS1 hola</ns:return></ns:getMessageServiceResponse>
```

My question is how Can I manipulate/How can get the response in Java program because I need the response. I tried to do a lot of things but unfortunately did not work anything I only can see the response in the console but I need to manipulate the response.

I do not how can I access this configuration or if I need to configurate other things.

```html
access<stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="messageChannelOUT"  append-newline="true" />
```

Can Anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway).

   ```
   public interface Gateway

       String sendAndReceive(String out);

   }

   <int:gateway service-interface="foo.Gateway" 
        default-request-channel="messageChannelIN" />
   ```
2. Remove the `output-channel` from the chain
3. The reply will be returned to the caller via the gateway

   ```
   Gatweway gw = context.getBean(Gateway.class);
   ...
   String reply = gw.sendAndReceive(requestXml);
   ```

This has the added bonus of not exposing your application to the messaging infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell!!

Answer (score 0):

It's working my program right now!!. Thanks for your help Gary Russell!!! your comments were very useful.

The final code was:

**xml configuration**

```
........
<chain input-channel="messageChannelIN">
    <ws:header-enricher>
        <ws:soap-action value="getMessageService"/>
    </ws:header-enricher>
    <ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2-webservice/services/wservices?wsdl" />
</chain>

<gateway id="messageChannelOUT" service-interface="org.neos.spring.ws.service.GatewayAxis" default-request-channel="messageChannelIN"/>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public interface GatewayAxis {
  @Gateway
  String sendAndReceive(String out);}
```

TestAxis2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-axis2-message.xml");

    GatewayAxis gateway = context.getBean(GatewayAxis.class);

    String requestXml = 
            "<getMessageService xmlns=\"http://service.ws.axis2.neos.org\">" + 
                    "<name>HUGO</name>"
            + "</getMessageService>";
    String reply = gateway.sendAndReceive(requestXml);
    System.out.println(reply);

}
```