# How to properly create RabbitMQ custom message from Java bean with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I am new in Spring Integration and maybe this question is trivial.  I am looking at the example (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp) creating RabbitMq message from stdin:

```
<int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="consoleIn"
    channel="toRabbit">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="toRabbit" />
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
    channel="toRabbit" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
    exchange-name-expression="payload.toLowerCase() == 'nack' ? 'badExchange' : 'si.test.exchange'"
    routing-key-expression="payload.toLowerCase() == 'fail' ? 'badKey' : 'si.test.binding'"
    confirm-correlation-expression="payload"
    confirm-ack-channel="good"
    confirm-nack-channel="errors"
    return-channel="returns" />
```

What if we need to have a custom message, produced in Java code.  What will be the proper elegant code?  The bean to populate the message is simplified:

```
package com.mycompany.domain.price;    
public class UpdateMessage implements Serializable {
Date effStartDate;
Date effEndDate;
Long orderId = -1;
String customerFullName;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641081/how-can-i-get-the-response-message-from-axis2-in-spring-integration/33642988#33642988); although it's talking about Axis instead of RabbitMQ; the same techniques apply.

Since your `UpdateMessage` implements `Serializable`, the standard message converter will take care of the conversion to a `byte[]` for you.

Sending a message with no reply, your gateway interface method might be

```
public void send(UpdateMessage msg);
```

In which case you'd you use an outbound channel adapter. If you want to get a reply, use an amqp outbound gateway and the service interface might look like

```
public UpdateResult send(UpdateMessage msg);
```

If you're not using `Serializable` objects, use of a json converter might be appropriate instead.

Comment: Gary,  thank you! Previously I used Listener for messaging.  Is current implementation better?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Your question was about sending messages not receiving them. If you are talking about using Spring Integration inbound adapter Vs. a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, the former uses the latter internally. It really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Gary, great. The last question:  What is an advantage of using Spring Integration inbound adapter Vs. a SimpleMessageListenerContainer?

Comment: In entirely depends on your application; if you wish to apply common [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) to your messages (filter, splitter, router etc), then consider using SI. If you're doing something simple, just use a container. The same thing applies on the publishing side, for simple use cases, consider just using a `RabbitTemplate`. However, using SI means you can make changes later without having to rewrite a lot of code.